# Converting a given string to datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to convert a string '2022-06-27 17:00:1656349200' to datetime, using

```
t = '2022-06-27 17:00:1656349200'
t__ = time.strptime(t, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
ts = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(t__))
dt = ts.replace(microsecond=int(frag))
print(dt)
```

But getting an error :
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 56349200

Comment: zero minutes 1656349200 seconds?! What datetime is that supposed to represent?

Comment: 1656349200 can't be as seconds goes from 0 to 59. Also yout `strptime` line is incorrect, you need a space inside like `t__ = time.strptime(t, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`. On another note, what's the variable `frag`

Comment: Have you thought about what might be wrong? e.g. there are only 60 seconds in a minute. We might guess that this broken time format is seconds concatenated with a decimal part, but 2 + 8 digits is a strange length for that (microseconds would be 6 digits after the decimal point, nanoseconds would be 9 digits). If you assume concatenation and are happy to truncate the decimal you can parse it with `datetime.strptime(t[:-2], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%f")`

Answer (score 2):

That date string looks a bit off. Normally you'd separate the milliseconds from the seconds with a dot: `2022-06-27 17:00:16.563`. Dot or not, you can read milliseconds with `%f`. So this gets you close:

```
datetime.strptime(t, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%f")
```

Unfortunately this will still complain about the last two digits:

```
>>> datetime.strptime("2022-06-27 17:00:1656349200", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%f")
...
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 00
```

So the `%f` can read the milliseconds and the microseconds, but the last two digits are too much. So the question becomes: Do you really need *nanosecond* precision? What are these zeroes doing there? Python's `datetime` cannot represent nanoseconds, so you'd have to use another data structure to store them.

If you don't need that much precision, and the date strings you are reading are always the same format, just cut them off:

```
datetime.strptime(t[:25], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%f")
```

It could also be that the last two digits are something else, like a timezone. But when things are mashed together like that, it is not clear what they are supposed to represent. So my recommendation ist o ignore everything after the seconds, unless you know what it is:

```
datetime.strptime(t[:19], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: since the first part of the OP's example string seems to be ISO format, I think it is safe to use `t[:19]`. You can then add the fractional seconds after coercion to microseconds, `int(t[19:25])` for example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the `.strptime()` parsing string parameter as follows:

```
import time
import datetime

t = '2022-06-27 17:00:1656349200'[:-2]
t__ = time.strptime(t, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%f")
ts = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(t__))
dt = ts.replace(microsecond=int(frag))
print(dt)
```

Comment: Yeah but you altered the input

Comment: @timgeb Yes, because the  last 2 digits are unnecessary

Comment: I meant that you sneakily added a dot ;) IMO we need to find out why there isn't one in OP's input first.

Comment: we don't actually know that he considers `1656349200` as `16.56349200`

Comment: @timgeb I tested it with a dot and forget to remove it, but it works on the same way

Comment: @nicocaldo This answer is based on the information available on the question. It would be great if we knew why is the input like that